# JSP start page error : Error resolving template, template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a spring boot application in which I want to start the application 
 with a Start.jsp page. The Start page is not able not load. it is in the resources/templates folder.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

     <form id="messageForm" action="sendMessage" method="post">
   <div>Personal Information</div>
      <div>
           <!-- Name attribute of fields is the same as the corresponding Java class-->
           <label>Name</label> <input name="name" value="" type="text"> 
      </div>
   <div>Message Details</div>
 <div>
      <label>To number</label> <input name="toNumber" value="" type="text">
           <label>From number</label> <input name="fromNumber" value="" type="text">
          <label>Message Body</label> <input name="messageBody" value="" type="text">
     </div>
  <div>
  <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Send Message</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

controller looks like :

```
package com.smsService;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class WebController {

      @RequestMapping(value = "/")
       public String index() {
      return "Start";
   }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMessage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public void sendMessage(Message message){

//code for controller
           return ;
   }
}
```

Message.java is an entity class which has the same names as fields in the form.

Expected result should be a form, where I can put data and submit

But I am getting is below error:

---

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jan 20 13:41:59 EST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [Start], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

---

Also when I use an html file it works, but not for a jsp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the below steps :

add following in application.properties :

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

added below code in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Made sure that structure /WEB-INF/jsp/ has my jsp files and is added to my classpath(in eclipse open build path and then add the source)